# SQL Row-Level Security multiple users and for sysadmin

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, row-level-security

So, I was doing Row-level security policy when I noticed that when I apply it, it works as it should be for the users. But for me as sysadmin I can't see the table content anymore. Because the policy hides it from me, too.

How can I add myself to see the table also?

```
CREATE function [tst].[turva] (@yritys sysname, @username AS VARCHAR(50))
returns table
with Schemabinding
as
return select 1 as [turva_tulos]
from 
tst.Customer
where @yritys = user_name()
OR
@username = SUSER_NAME() --im still not getting the results.
```

Answer (score 0):

If `@username` is database user name, the condition `@username = SUSER_NAME()` cannot be true for sysadmin.

`SUSER_NAME()` is a login of sysadmin while in database sysadmin is always mapped as `dbo`

I.e. the condition for sysadmin should be

```
OR
@username = 'dbo'
```